# launch a windows app after a particular event

Tags: c++, user-interface, event-handling, smartcard-reader

I would like to launch a GUI app after an event arrived (in my case the user inserted its smartcard).

First I thought about creating a service waiting for the user to insert the smartcard and then launching the GUI app.
The problem is that I read the services run in Session 0 and because of it they can't launch a GUI app.

What are the alternatives that I could use?

Comment: Just have it run from  \startup or hkcu../run and sit in the background?

Comment: Yeah I'm going to think about it. And a service running as local System can interact with the user session?